# When is it appropriate to use metamodels instead of an expensive analysis?

Tags: openmdao

When should one consider using a metamodel in place of an expensive analysis component? I haven't actually seen an example of an openMDAO project that uses metamodels yet, so I was wondering if they're recommended or whether it's still best to treat expensive analyses like normal ones.

Comment: The first question is: the expensive analysis takes 1 min or 1 week? In the former case I might consider treating it as a normal component, but in the latter I would go for a metamodel. The second question is: is the output probabilistic? A metamodel might add some nice regularity to the output, which might be very valuable close to the optimum and for computing the partials.

Answer (score 2):

Using a metamodel is a trade-off. You trade accuracy vs execution time so it is up to you in your context.